# How to make a fluid, stacked column layout in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I need to build a layout similar to the one at www.PInterest.com, where - depending on the browser width (yes responsive design) the amount of columns varies. The problem is not the horizontal stacking but the vertical. How do i make the boxes different height and stack on top of each other som that it will not let the highest box determine the height for the entire row?

Using ASP.NET MVC 3, HTML/HTML5, CSS/CSS3

Comment: think of columns instead of rows. http://stackoverflow.com/q/9205790/575527 and by the way, pinterest "columns" are not actual columns. they are dynamically placed divs, each positioned allover the page. debug the page, all "sections" are made of **sibling divs** distributed into columns.

Answer (score 2):

Make three elements (`div`, for example), that are fluid in their width. These will serve as your columns. Put the elements you want inside each column with the respective `<div>`.

I just made this as an example: http://jsfiddle.net/N4zkF/

I think viewing the example would be more helpful than me explaining it in words. The three columns are bordered in red, blue, and green. The content of each has a gray/black background and a fixed height.

---

This answer was edited. Last time I linked the wrong jsfiddle (was wondering why I got a downvote). Hopefully this will help you, OP.

Answer (score 1):

u need to set the width of the colums with a percentage and have a `min-width` on each of the columns..

Say u want 3 column's,for a responsive design -- set the width of all 3 columns as `width:33%` and add a min-width for the least resolution that you are supporting,

say,`1024x768` in that case -- `1000px is the total width that you might have at the minimum` (ignoring the extra 24px for the browsers scroll bar on each sides).. so,let the `min-width:333px`.. so,if the width of the browser is more,it'll occupy the space.. else,min-width will be set anyway so you need not worry about the layout getting screwed..

here's a fiddle to get you started - jsfiddle.net/mvivekc/XwYDr

here's a nice tutorial that i stumbled upon

-- http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-multi-column-liquid-layouts

-- http://css-tricks.com/the-perfect-fluid-width-layout/