# How to create unique html table?

Tags: html, css

I have problem to create table like image below:
[image]
Does anyone know how to create table above using html and css?
I Use that table to create content like this below:
[image]
Please guide me and thanks in advance.

Comment: In order to avoid a ton of rowspans why don't you just create 2 simple tables side by side?

Comment: Is this for displaying tabular data, or is this a page layout?

Comment: You may be interested in this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9205790/making-a-column-oriented-table-in-html

Comment: For other complex table layouts, [**this site**](http://www.eobcards.com/tablet.htm) has a ton of live examples with the markup required.

Comment: great references but can't solve my problem

Answer (score 3):

rowspan=2 will let you merge cells vertically.

E.g. here is the start of your table:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 TRANSITIONAL//EN"><HTML>
<BODY>
<table border>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan=2>row 1, column 1</td>
    <td>row 1, column 2</td>
    <td>row 1, column 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <!--td row 2, column 1, covered by row above-->
    <td rowspan=2>row 2, column 2</td>
    <td>row 2, column 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>row 3, column 1</td>
    <!--td row 3, column 2, covered by row above-->
    <td>row 3, column 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

To generate tables like that manually gets messy pretty quickly.  You'd be better off with a good layout tool.

Answer (score 1):

Make a table of 6 rows by 3 columns and make some of the borders invisible, this would be the easiest. I think you can figure the rest of it out by yourself.